# How to send a webservice request in jmeter to https rather than http

Tags: web-services, soap, https, jmeter

I have created a new project using the template 'Building a SOAP WebService Test Plan' in jmeter (followed the steps in the tutorial from the apache jmeter website to set this up). The responses aren't being accepted and in the results log I am seeing the message:

1446205258738,20995,Soap Request,Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException,Non HTTP response message: Connection to http://(server name).com refused,Number of Users 1-10,text,false,2273,1,1,0

It's making the connection to http rather than https which I think is why the connection is not being made. Is there anyway to change this? I've tried using the different implementations in the soap request but this hasn't worked, currently using HttpClient4.

Please see the http request details
[HTTP REQUEST DETAILS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OE1xD.png)

Comment: Put `https` in the text box that says `Protocol [http]:`

Comment: Thanks for the comment (@ubik load pack below) I've tried that and now I'm getting: 1446212627785,23,Soap Request,404,Not Found,Number of Users 1-3,text,false,1405,1,1,23

Comment: How do you invoke your SOAP service before you got jmeter involved?

Comment: RaGe Sorry I'm not understanding the question? I should also say I got this error message when I added the results tree to my project:  Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'.

Comment: @RaGe I used SOAP UI which was able to send the request and generate a reposponse, I don't know why jmeter is proving so hard :L

Comment: For the new error, change your HTTP header manager content-type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Answer (score 1):

As per @Rage answer (who should answer in response not comment , I'll be happy to remove my answer if he does), just change :

> Protocol [http] value to https

See:
[image]

As per your last comment, you modified to https and now you face another issue , getting a 404.
So most probably your **Path** or **Server Name or IP** are wrong, as the hoster or developer for the correct connection informations.

Comment: This change now gives me the error message: 1446212627785,23,Soap Request,404,Not Found,Number of Users 1-3,text,false,1405,1,1,23

Comment: You are getting a 404 which means your URL is probably wrong. Show how you configured your HTTP Request.

Comment: Thanks @UBIK LOAD PACK, i'll try and attached a screenshot now

Comment: Please see attached under the main question text.

Comment: Thanks @UBIKLOADPACK I answered as a comment only because I was fairly certain OP's problem is not https. If a server is https only, it would usually automatically redirect from http to https. OP just confirmed they have bigger problems :)